# Type of MySQL Decimal value in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, bc

I am using `BC Math` library in PHP, as you know data provided to BC functions MUST BE strings, otherwise very weird results might come out.

I am storing decimal values (18,10) in MySQL.

My questions are:

1. What is the type of these values when i fetch them in PHP, are they string? and can i use them directly in BC such as `bcmul($database_decimal_value , '1', '10')` ?
2. Can i use output of BC functions (which is string i guess) and insert in MySQL decimal type directly?

P.S. i have read the MySQL reference and it says: `Values for DECIMAL columns no longer are represented as strings that require 1 byte per digit or sign character.` not sure if this means they are no longer strings.

## Edit:

I test the answer with the following code:

```
<?php
$var = 0.00001;
echo bcmul('10', "$var", '5');
?>
```

But it echoes `0` instead of `0.00010` !
if i change `$var = 0.00001` to `$var = '0.00001';` (which is string) it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of whether the value itself is a string or a number, you can force it to be passed as a string <strike>using proper quotes</strike> using `strval()`

```
bcmul(strval($database_decimal_value) , '1', '10');
```

And yes, you can pass those values to MySQL without quotes and it will treat them as numbers

Comment: Thank you very much, same goes for my second question right?

Comment: Other way around for database, send to database without quotes.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work, Could you please kindly check my `Edit` above?

Comment: `echo bcmul('10', "$variable", '5');` use that

Comment: I used that and same result (updated edit), only works if i use `$var = '0.00001';`